# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer failing to recognize gesture on right edge

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am having an issue where i have defined a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to detect pan gesture appearing on the right edge of my device but the gesture is recognized sporadically:

I have the following code:

```
 _swipeInLeftGestureRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeInFromRightEdge:)];
 _swipeInLeftGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
 _swipeInLeftGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
 [_swipeInLeftGestureRecognizer setEdges:UIRectEdgeRight];
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_swipeInLeftGestureRecognizer];

- (void)handleSwipeInFromRightEdge:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"swipe from right edge!!!!");
}
```

The gesture is attached to a view with nothing on it.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to create a workaround. It is pretty straightforward. I've subclassed UIWindow and used touchesBegan/touchesMoved/etc. methods to simulate gesture recognition.

It works. UIWindow is not rotated automatically, so I have to transform touch coordinates accordingly.

Here is my version of the transformation:

```
- (CGPoint)transformPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    CGPoint pointInView = point;

    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        pointInView.x = self.bounds.size.width - pointInView.x;
        pointInView.y = self.bounds.size.height - pointInView.y;
    } else if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        CGFloat x = pointInView.x;
        CGFloat y = pointInView.y;
        pointInView = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.height - y, x);
    } else if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        CGFloat x = pointInView.x;
        CGFloat y = pointInView.y;
        pointInView = CGPointMake(y, self.bounds.size.width - x);
    }
    return pointInView;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a little more detail about how you are doing it? I'm seeing exactly the same issue as described by ultra, i.e. if the camera is on the right side, the detection is sporadical. Were you transforming touch coordinates when you are adding the gesture (if so, how?) or inside the gesture's action method? In my case when i try to add the gesture to the window, the method doesn't get triggered at all on landscape (still works for portrait). Thanks a lot.

Comment: I ended up creating a UIWindow subclass with touchesBegan/touchesMoved/etc. overriding. I catch events there and transform touch point according to screen orientation. Updated my answer to include transformation code.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's bugs.  My app is always in landscape mode, and I've set up the same thing as you, with it detecting the right edge.  If that edge is the camera side of the iPad, it detects sporadically.  If I flip over the iPad and the right edge is the button side, it works just fine.  In fact, I'm having this problem with any gesture, not just this one.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, it helped me to create a workaround.